# Storing profile image in Base64 format in database for Hybrid Mobile Application

Tags: javascript, telerik, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder

I am using Telerik Platform Kendo Mobile to build mobile app ,I am using cordova camera and gallery plugin to catpure the profile picture, this picture converted into Base64,Now my question is this best way to store Base64 data in database or is there any alternative way to store Profile Picture/Images for Mobile application, and i want to make popup also when user click on Profile Pic

Answer (score 0):

There is an "image" data type, but according to MSDN you don't want to use it anymore as it's on the way out.  Looks like you probably want to use varbinary(max).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Either that or store the images on your server and have a path saved in the database.